# PHP Form showing unpredictable error

Tags: php, forms

The php code below echoes the image by using the variables $cat & $var, but when I fill the form & press submit, it shows following error redirecting to the same page instead of going to insert.php. The error is :

> Notice: Undefined index: number in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\k\show_results_4.php on line 161
>
> Notice: Undefined index: category in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\k\show_results_4.php on line 162
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\k\show_results_4.php on
>   line 164

**

```
    <?php  
                       $var=$_GET['number'];                 //line 161
                        $cat=$_GET['category'];              // line 162
                        $unipath= array('breads','fruits','milk','vegetables');
                        echo $unipath[$cat];                  //line 164
                      echo '<img alt="140x140" src="/k/images/'.$unipath[$cat].'/'.$var.'.jpg" class="img-rounded"/>';


        if(isset($_SESSION['stats']))
            $mode=$_SESSION['stats'];
            if($mode=='vendor')
            {
                echo "<form method='POST' action='insert.php'>
                    Enter price per item/kg:<input type='text' name='pr'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vegid' value='".$var."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vegcat' value='".$cat."'><br/>
                <br/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'> SUBMIT </button>
                </form>";
                        ?>
```

**For reference the insert.php is :**

```
<?php
include 'conf.inc.php';
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']))
header('Location:login.php?t=1');
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$vegid=$_POST['vegid'];
$vegcat=$_POST['vegcat'];
if(isset($_POST['pr']))
    {
        $price=$_POST['pr']; 
        if(!empty($price))
        {
            $dur=date('d m Y',time());
                        $query="insert into daily values('".$dur."','".$vegid."','".$vegcat."','".$id."','".$price."')";
                        if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
                        {
                                header('Location:Homepage_2.php?suc=1');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                header('Location:Homepage_2.php?suc=2');
                        }
                }
            else
            {
        header('Location:Homepage_2.php?suc=3');
        }
        echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: `$var=isset($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : '';`

Comment: Form which you submit has method GET or POST? I guess its POST and you are trying to access via GET variable??

Comment: When looking at your source code in the browser, do you see any issues with the form code? Many browsers such as firefox etc. will show source code in red if there is an HTML error. I am wondering if perhaps you have another element somewhere (maybe even another form element) that was not properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not errors, they are notices....

> Notice: Undefined index: number in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\k\show_results_4.php on line 161

You are trying to retrieve the value of `$_GET['number']` without check if `$_GET['number']` exists

> Notice: Undefined index: category in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\k\show_results_4.php on line 162

You are trying to retrieve the value of `$_GET['category']` without check if `$_GET['category']` exists

> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\k\show_results_4.php on
>   line 164

Since you are trying to get access to $unipath[$cat] and $cat is not set you are trying to get the value of $unipath[] (no index)

In order to use any index value, please check if it exists first.

How?

```
$variable = isset($array['index']) ? $array['index'] : 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $var=$_GET['number'];
        $cat=$_GET['category'];
        $unipath= array('breads','fruits','milk','vegetables');
        echo $unipath[$cat];
        echo '<img alt="140x140" src="/k/images/'.$unipath[$cat].'/'.$var.'.jpg" class="img-rounded"/>';

        if(isset($_SESSION['stats']))
            $mode=$_SESSION['stats'];
        if($mode=='vendor')
        {
            echo "<form method='POST' action='insert.php'>
            Enter price per item/kg:<input type='text' name='pr'>
            <input type='hidden' name='vegid' value='" . $var . "'>
            <input type='hidden' name='vegcat' value='" . $cat . "'><br/>
            <br/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit'> SUBMIT </button>//add name field
            </form>";
        }
    }

?>
```

**Note :** you are sending data through `POST` method. So assign your variables with `$_POST`. (Ex: `$var=$_POST['number'];` and `$cat=$_POST['category'];`)